# Supplying tour dates for artists

Tags: spotify

I get questions about the tour dates an artist can activate in their verified profile. Is it possible to supply these via an API on Spotify?

Thanks!

Regards,
Marlon

Answer (score 2):

No, it's not possible. You might want to check out [Songkick's API](http://www.songkick.com/developer) with over 3 million concerts though.